# How can I get all the plain text from a website with Scrapy?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to have all the text visible from a website, after the HTML is rendered. I'm working in Python with Scrapy framework.
With `xpath('//body//text()')` I'm able to get it, but with the HTML tags, and I only want the text. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The easiest option would be to [`extract`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) `//body//text()` and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) everything found:

```
''.join(sel.select("//body//text()").extract()).strip()
```

where `sel` is a [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) instance.

Another option is to use [`nltk`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk)'s `clean_html()`:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> html = """
... <div class="post-text" itemprop="description">
... 
...         <p>I would like to have all the text visible from a website, after the HTML is rendered. I'm working in Python with Scrapy framework.
... With <code>xpath('//body//text()')</code> I'm able to get it, but with the HTML tags, and I only want the text. Any solution for this? Thanks !</p>
... 
...     </div>"""
>>> nltk.clean_html(html)
"I would like to have all the text visible from a website, after the HTML is rendered. I'm working in Python with Scrapy framework.\nWith xpath('//body//text()') I'm able to get it, but with the HTML tags, and I only want the text. Any solution for this? Thanks !"
```

Another option is to use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)'s `get_text()`:

> `get_text()`
>
> If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you
>   can use the `get_text()` method. It returns all the text in a document
>   or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.get_text().strip()
I would like to have all the text visible from a website, after the HTML is rendered. I'm working in Python with Scrapy framework.
With xpath('//body//text()') I'm able to get it, but with the HTML tags, and I only want the text. Any solution for this? Thanks !
```

Another option is to use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)'s `text_content()`:

> `.text_content()`
>
> Returns the text content of the element, including
>   the text content of its children, with no markup.

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
>>> print tree.text_content().strip()
I would like to have all the text visible from a website, after the HTML is rendered. I'm working in Python with Scrapy framework.
With xpath('//body//text()') I'm able to get it, but with the HTML tags, and I only want the text. Any solution for this? Thanks !
```

Comment: I have deleted my question.. I have used the below code     html = sel.select("//body//text()")
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
        item['description'] = tree.text_content().strip()  But i am getting the      is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
 exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer ..erro. What went wrong

Comment: Just as an update, `nltk` deprecated their `clean_html` method and instead recommend:
`NotImplementedError: To remove HTML markup, use BeautifulSoup's get_text() function
`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried?

```
xpath('//body//text()').re('(\w+)')
```

OR

```
 xpath('//body//text()').extract()
```

Comment: This actually works quite fine, but still returns some html tags and others.

Answer (score 1):

The `xpath('//body//text()')` doesn't always drive dipper into the nodes in your last used tag(in your case body.) If you type `xpath('//body/node()/text()').extract()` you will see the nodes which are in you html body. You can try `xpath('//body/descendant::text()')`.