# Scrapy xpath for nested elements

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I think I am using Scrapy wrong, but I am trying to use xpath to select only the text from the H2's on a page and strip out the inner tags.

eg.

```
<h2>Welcome to my <a href="#">page</a></h2>
<h2>Welcome to my Page</h2>
```

I have tried using `//h2//text()`,  but it produces an array like this

```
item["h2s"] = response.xpath('//h2//text()').extract()

['Welcome to my',
'page',
'Welcome to my Page']
```

I have tried number of combinations and just can't seem to get an array like I want below

```
['Welcome to my page',
'Welcome to my Page']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may *join* all the text nodes for every `h2`:

```
In [1]: [''.join(h2.xpath(".//text()").extract()) for h2 in response.xpath("//h2")]
Out[1]: [u'Welcome to my page', u'Welcome to my Page']
```

This topic is also quite relevant:

- [How can I get all the plain text from a website with Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156780/how-can-i-get-all-the-plain-text-from-a-website-with-scrapy)

Comment: Fantastic, just tried it and worked perfectly :) thanks.   It seems like quite a complex thing to do in Scrapy for something relatively simple.