# Scrapy: Scraping all the text from a website but not the text of hyperlinks

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have found helpful links explaining how to extract all the text from the body here: [How can I get all the plain text from a website with Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156780/how-can-i-get-all-the-plain-text-from-a-website-with-scrapy)

However, in the process of extracting all the text, it also scrapes the text of the hyperlinks which I do not want. For example when scraping the website: http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/page/1/

I used the following extractor:

```
text = re.sub(' +',' ',re.sub('\n|\t|\r','',' '.join(response.selector.xpath('//body/descendant-or-self::*[not( self::script | self::style)]/text()').extract()))).strip()
```

I got the output of:

> "Quotes to Scrape Login Viewing tag: humor “The person, be it
>   gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be
>   intolerably stupid.” by ...."

The word "Login" comes from the text portion of the hyperlink

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

Another example of a text coming from a hyperlink is:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tab" class="login-tab-links2 toplogin">KFN PUBlIC INVESTORS<small>K1 AND TAX INFO</small></a></li>
```

Where 'KFN PUBlIC INVESTORS' and 'K1 AND TAX INFO' get scraped too.

How can I avoid having text from the hyperlinks being scraped too?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether nodes `parent` or an `ancestor` is a node you dont want.

For example:
This xpath will find all text of nodes that are not children of `<a>` nodes:

```
//text()[not(parent::a)]
```

Alternatively you can use `ancestor` which checks whether any of the ancestors are `<a>` nodes (this means a parent, grandparent, grandgrandparent and so on):

```
//text()[not(ancestor::a)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried using two forms of the [not(parent::a)] paradigm. `'//body/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script | self::style | ancestor::a )]/text()')` as well as `'//body/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script | self::style )]/text()[not(ancestor::a)]')` but both did not work. Lastly i tried the simple way `'//body//text()[not(parent::a)]')` and that didn't work either. Is there anything I'm doing wrongly (I tried both combinations with parents and ancestors)?

Comment: @BenedictLim what do you mean by did not work? it captures text under `<a>` node? Could you elaborate more what result are you expcting?

Comment: Actually I tried `'//body/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script | self::style | self::a )]/text()'`, but replacing ancestor with self and it worked for the most part! I think if i keep excluding elements in this format should be able to reduce the types of text I want to avoid. Thanks!